# I want to make my single-tenant eve application multi-tenant, perhaps using flask-login

Tags: flask, flask-login, eve

I currently have a single-tenant eve app which works great, but would like to make it multi-tenant.  That is, I want to allow multiple users to login where each gets a totally separate database (or different tables?).

I looked at flask-login for managing the user login (and registration) piece, but I am unclear on how to integrate this into my existing eve app so that each user has a different database.

The eve documentation at http://python-eve.org/authentication.html#auth-driven-database-access has the sample below.

```
from eve.auth import BasicAuth

class MyBasicAuth(BasicAuth):
    def check_auth(self, username, password, allowed_roles, resource, method):
        if username == 'user1':
            self.set_mongo_prefix('MONGO1')
        elif username == 'user2':
            self.set_mongo_prefix('MONGO2')
        else:
            # serve all other users from the default db.
            self.set_mongo_prefix(None)
        return username is not None and password == 'secret'

app = Eve(auth=MyBasicAuth)
app.run()
```

However, this assumes that MONGO1 and MONGO2 are statically defined in my settings.py.  Is there a way to dynamically create a new database for each user which is registered with my app?

Thanks in advance,
Keith